# JavaFX Application Bootup in Windows 8

Tags: java, windows, javafx, windows-8

Is it possible that to run a JavaFX Application at windows boot time. what efforts i can make so that my java application automatically starts when windows(OS) start or boots ? (after displaying a windows logo, before desktop mode load)

Comment: I think that Java (and definitely java fx) is too dependent on other sources (like the JVM) to succesfully launch at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success packaging JavaFX applications into an .exe using the JavaFX Maven Plugin (https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin). You even have the option to bundle a JRE with it so it doesn't need to rely on the system's installed JRE.  I imagine once you create the .exe, you can simply add it to your "Startup" folder. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2806079)

Comment: in startup folder, application is only run after the desktop loaded. what I want is execute the application in boot time. before desktop is loaded.

Comment: @Hiran did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [this link](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunJavaApplicationAsAService.html). The program "AlwaysUp" has unrestricted 30-day trial version. Try that and if you like it and don't want to pay for it, you can find the full version from torrent.